# MySQL count elements in a database based on how many unique values there are in a field

Tags: mysql

(Sorry for the title, I don't really know how to phrase that :-) )

I have a table that has a date and a uid fields.

I need to get the number of uid for each date, currently I'm doing it in php running multiple queries like this one:

```
SELECT COUNT(uid) FROM users where Date = 'xxx';
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this with only an sql query?

Comment: Do you want to count the unique values or the total number of rows? Your title and your query contradict each other. Or is `uid` unique in this table? In which case there is no difference. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the group by clause:

```
SELECT Date, COUNT(uid) FROM users group by Date;
```

Comment: @0plus1: Note that this doesn't count unique values, it counts **all** values. If this is what you wanted you should probably adjust the title of the question to match.

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of unique values use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uid) AS cnt
FROM users
GROUP BY `Date`
```

If your column is a datetime then you should use the [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function to get the date part only:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT uid) AS cnt
FROM users
GROUP BY DATE(`Date`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Date, COUNT(uid) FROM users GROUP BY Date
```